# Order by inside Group_concat

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by, group-concat

[This](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a3554d/1) is my fiddle.

Table and data is

```
create table Table3 (MatchID varchar(10), ItemType varchar(10));
insert into Table3 values
('M001','Fruit'),
('M001','Animal'),
('M002','Fruit'),
('M002','Vehicle');
```

When you have a select query orderd by MatchID  and ItemType , it is returning

```
select MatchID,ItemType from Table3 order by MatchID,ItemType;

    MATCHID ITEMTYPE
    M001    Animal
    M001    Fruit
    M002    Fruit
    M002    Vehicle
```

like this, which is expected and correct.

However when I group_concated, it is not returning in an ordered manner.

```
Select group_concat(ItemType) as typesTomatch ,MatchID
from (select MatchID,ItemType from Table3 
      order by MatchID,ItemType)
c group by MatchID;
```

It is returning

```
TYPESTOMATCH    MATCHID
Fruit,Animal    M001
Fruit,Vehicle   M002
```

against expected

```
TYPESTOMATCH    MATCHID
Animal,Fruit    M001
Fruit,Vehicle   M002
```

. Why group_concat behaves so? How to produce the expected output?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `ORDER BY` inside [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(ItemType ORDER BY ItemType) AS typesTomatch , MatchID
FROM Table3 GROUP BY MatchID;
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a3554d/8)

Comment: you saved my day.. Dont know about order by inside GROUP_CONCAT(). Thats cool

Comment: you kicked out a result set too.. +1 for all